# Improve running time in T-sql code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to Improve running time in T-sql code.

The Insert query is taking a long time. Is there any chance to use a different method ?
Here is my Code

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateTableDemog] 
 @Age int,
 @RetiredAge int 
as
begin


declare @t as int=1;
declare @tlast as int=@RetiredAge -@Age 
declare @Period as int=0;
BEGIN
    while @t<=@tlast
    begin

        while @Period <=@t-1
        begin

        INSERT INTO dbo.Table (t, Age,Period,Prob)
                    VALUES (@t,@Age+@t,@Period,1);


        set @Period=@Period+1  
        end     
        set @Period=0               
        set @t=@t+1 
    end
end
```

Comment: Please share your attempts to optimize this query.

Comment: The performance of this is going to stink because you are using a loop. You should instead use a numbers/tally table and make your entire procedure a single set based insert statement.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you could do this using a tally table instead of the nested while loops. This is a strange requirement but easy enough to follow.

This article by Jeff Moden does a great job of explaining what a tally is and how you can use it. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateTableDemog] 
(
    @Age int
    , @RetiredAge int
) as

    set nocount on;

    WITH
        E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
        E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
        E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
        cteTally(N) AS 
        (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
        )

    INSERT INTO dbo.Table
    (
        t
        , Age
        , Period
        , Prob
    )
     select t1.N as T
        , @Age + t1.N as AgePlusT
        , abs(t2.N - t1.N) as Period
        , 1
     from cteTally t1
     join cteTally t2 on t2.N <= t1.N
     where t1.N <= @RetiredAge - @Age
     order by t1.N
        , @Age + t1.N
        , abs(t2.N - t1.N);

GO
```

Comment: If this works in your situation you should mark is as the answer.

Comment: Hi there,one more question Pls. instead of 1 in Prob Col,  i need to use the last interaction saved on dbo.Table. as Prob  = Prob *  (select Prob from dbo.Table where Period= abs(t2.N - t1.N) -1).Is it Possile? if not what should i do ?

Comment: Did you try it? Your explanation is extremely vague here.